# How to transition area along one axis in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying do some path interpolation in D3. I'd like to produce an area plot [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883196), but I want to transition the area along the y-axis, starting from the bottom of the xaxis up to the final position shown in the example. Here's a quick sketch to explain what I'd like to do:

I'd like to start the transition with no area:
[image]

and transition it up along the y-axis:

[image]

Using the code, copied from the example, here's what I'd trying to do:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  var dataSel = svg.selectAll('.area').data(data)

  dataSel.exit().remove()
  dataSel.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", 'M0,0h' + width)    // my idea here was to draw a path that 
                                   // has no area along the x-axis and then 
                                   // interpolate the path up to the final area

  dataSel.transition()             // transition the path to its final position
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", area)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
});
```

Can anyone explain/show how I can transition a path along one axis as I'm trying to do?

Comment: Your link is broken.. But it seems like what you need to do is change the y range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 path transitions only really work if the starting and ending paths have the same number of control points. So, for example, D3 can't transition a line into an area. What you could do, however, is something like the following:

1. Use `d3.area` to generate the final path for the area.
2. Make a copy of the path and, in the copy, change all the control points that correspond to the "top" of the area to control points on the "bottom" of the area. (In other words, modify their y-values.)
3. Draw the area using this modified path.
4. Transition to the final path.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the help; that approached worked! I didn't realized the paths needed the same number of control points.